# Get type of containing class

Tags: c++

I wish to have a macro that uses the type of the class it is used in without passing that name to the macro. To do this I tried `typedef decltype(*this) my_type;`, but `this` can only be used within non-static member functions. Any ideas?

EDIT (copy of comments):

I've made a base class and set of macros that seamlessly implement triple buffering of a class's data using CRTP. The complication comes when a triple buffered class inherits from another triple buffered class, effectively having two bases - the CRTP base hidden in a macro and the explicit base. Because the explicit base also inherits from a different instantiation of the CRTP base, member functions in the derived class conflict between the two bases. I am writing a macro to automatically resolve this conflict with a reimplementation of the functions within the derived class. This reimplementation requires the type of the derived class to access the correct instantiation of the CRTP class, hence the original question.

Comment: Wait, so are you telling me you are writing inside the class, but don't know inside which one?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this particular approach?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, indirectly via a macro.

Comment: @Dylan That's not what I asked. If you are writing inside a class, *why* can't use use the class name?

Comment: This looks like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually after?

Comment: I've made a base class and set of macros that seamlessly implement triple buffering of a class's data using CRTP. The complication comes when a triple buffered class inherits from another triple buffered class, effectively having two bases - the CRTP base hidden in a macro and the explicit base. Because the explicit base also inherits from a different instantiation of the CRTP base, member functions in conflict between the two bases. I am writing a macro to automatically resolve this conflict with a reimplementation of the functions within the derived class. (continued...)

Comment: *DISCLAIMER: THIS IS UGLY*: You cannot do that, but you could define a macro that defines the class *and* at the same time defines a typedef for the same name inside that class (if your class can have base classes, you'll need to define several variants of that macro I guess). But that's fetish, really. Just live with having your macro accept the class name.

Comment: @Dylan It would be better to add this much info by editing the question.

Comment: (continuation) This reimplementation requires the type of the derived class to access the correct instantiation of the CRTP class, hence the original question, and why I didn't elaborate.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I was just wondering whether it was possible, to minimise on redundant information being provided by the end user.

Comment: Using a macro certainly isn't a good way to do it.

Comment: The whole reason for all these macros is to hide the fact that a CRTP class cannot use member types of the derived class, so macros are used to define these types elsewhere.

Comment: Another reason for the macros is to avoid misuse of CRTP (since it is not enforceable directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WARNING**: The following is *not* standard conforming. It only works if I pass `-fpermissive` to GCC and it prints an ugly warning when compiled:

```
#include <type_traits>

#define JOIN( A, B ) JOIN_INTERNAL( A, B )
#define JOIN_INTERNAL( A, B ) A##B
#define UNIQUE_NAME JOIN( unique_prefix_to_typedef_this_, __LINE__ )

template< typename T > struct class_type;
template< typename T, typename C > struct class_type< T C::* > { typedef C type; };

#define TYPEDEF_THIS void UNIQUE_NAME(); typedef class_type< decltype( &UNIQUE_NAME ) >::type

struct A
{
  TYPEDEF_THIS my_type;
  static_assert( std::is_same< my_type, A >::value, "my_type is not A if this fails" );
};

int main()
{
}
```

I hope you can use it, otherwise I'm pretty sure there is no standard conforming solution.

Comment: I was hoping for a standard conforming solution. However if no other solution is presented soon I will accept your answer.